# XPath test if node value is number

Tags: xpath

How can I check if a node value is a number using XPath?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Test the value against [NaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256038.aspx):

```
<xsl:if test="string(number(myNode)) != 'NaN'">
    <!-- myNode is a number -->
</xsl:if>
```

This is a shorter version (thanks [@Alejandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/357812/alejandro)):

```
<xsl:if test="number(myNode) = myNode">
    <!-- myNode is a number -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Because in XPath 1.0 `NaN` value of number data type doesn't equal to any number value and for comparison if at least one argument is number data typed then the other is cast to number, this is the shortest number test: `number(MyNode)=MyNode`

Comment: The short version by @Alejandro completely fails with XPath 2.0 due to type mismatch on the = operator (`Required item type of first operand of '=' is numeric; supplied value has item type xs:string;`), Dimitre's solution works fine however.

Answer (score 75):

**The shortest possible way to test if the value contained in a variable `$v` can be used as a number is**:

```
number($v) = number($v)
```

You only need to substitute the `$v` above with the expression whose value you want to test.

**Explanation**:

`number($v) = number($v)` is obviously true, if `$v` is a number, or a string that represents a number.

It is true also for a boolean value, because a `number(true())` is 1 and `number(false)` is 0.

Whenever `$v` cannot be used as a number, then `number($v)` is NaN

and NaN is not equal to any other value, even to itself.

Thus, the above expression is true only for `$v` whose value can be used as a number, and false otherwise.

Comment: +1 helpful explanation. Can someone comment on cases where `number($v) = number($v)` yields a different result from `number($v) = $v`?

Comment: @LarsH: I already commented on these cases. Can you point out yet an undiscussed case?

Comment: I meant could someone list the cases where `number($v) = number($v)` yields a different result from `number($v) = $v`? Doubtless that's derivable from what you wrote, but I'm not seeing where you addressed this question explicitly. Sorry if I'm being dense. IOW, does your solution and @Oded's/@Alejandro's solution always yield the same results?

Comment: @LarsH: I haven't looked at Oded's solution because it is obviously something I wouldn't like to use. I think Al2jandro's solution and mine solution give the same answers for any value of $v

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the spec where it says that NaN is not equal to any other value, even itself? I can't find this in the Xpath spec (either 1.0 or 2.0). My concern is that this is not a specified behavior but just happens to be the behavior of an implementation.

Comment: @EricS, The facts about and properties of Double arithmetic are in another standard: Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers. IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic. ANSI/IEEE Std 754-1985. This is why the XPath specifications just point to this standard. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: @EricS, It seems one can only access the IEEE standard by purchasing it... Byt do have a look here: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF . In particular, this paragraph: *"IEEE 754 assigns values to all relational expressions involving NaN . In the syntax of C , the predicate
x != y is True but all others, x < y , x <= y , x == y , x >= y and x > y , are False whenever x or y or both are NaN"*

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I hadn't see the reference to the IEEE standard in the W3C Xpath spec. And actually I do see it in the XPath 1.0 spec, but I don't see it in the XPath 2.0 spec...but perhaps that one has another level of indirection.

Answer (score 22):

There's an amazing type test operator in XPath 2.0 you can use:

```
<xsl:if test="$number castable as xs:double">
    <!-- implementation -->
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 16):

I'm not trying to provide a yet another alternative solution, but a "meta view" to this problem.

Answers already provided by Oded and Dimitre Novatchev are correct but what people really might mean with phrase "value is a number" is, how would I say it, open to interpretation.

In a way it all comes to this bizarre sounding question: **"how do you want to express your numeric values?"**

XPath function `number()` processes numbers that have

- possible leading or trailing whitespace
- preceding sign character *only on negative values*
- *dot* as an decimal separator (optional for integers)
- all other characters from range [0-9]

Note that this doesn't include expressions for numerical values that

- are expressed in exponential form (e.g. 12.3E45)
- may contain sign character for positive values
- have a distinction between positive and negative zero
- include value for positive or negative infinity

These are not just made up criteria. An element with content that is according to schema a valid `xs:float` value might contain any of the above mentioned characteristics. Yet `number()` would return value `NaN`.

So answer to your question "How i can check with XPath if a node value is number?" is either "Use already mentioned solutions using `number()`" or "with a single XPath 1.0 expression, you can't". Think about the possible number formats you might encounter, and if needed, write some kind of logic for validation/number parsing. Within XSLT processing, this can be done with few suitable extra templates, for example.

PS. If you only care about non-zero numbers, the shortest test is

```
<xsl:if test="number(myNode)">
    <!-- myNode is a non-zero number -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: +1 Good detailed explanation of the issues behind the question: what the OP might have meant or would have meant if he'd known what to ask.

Answer (score 10):

The one I found very useful is the following:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="not(number(myNode))">
      <!-- myNode is a not a number or empty(NaN) or zero -->      
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- myNode is a number (!= zero) -->        
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always use something like this:

```
string(//Sesscode) castable as xs:decimal
```

castable is documented by W3C [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-castable).

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with 01 - which is a numeric.

`string(number($v)) != string($v)` makes the segregation