# xpath:number returns false for "0"

Tags: xslt, xpath, numbers, xslt-1.0

I have an `xsl:variable` that can be either the empty string or a number. So I evaluate it like this:

```
<xsl:if test="number($var)"><node att="{number($var)}" /></xsl:if>
```

This works if `var` is the empty string, but it has the same effect if `var` is `0`:

From -2 to 2:

```
<node att="-2" />
<node att="-1" />
<node att="1" />
<node att="2" />
```

Is this a bug? Is there a different version of the `number` function that also captures `0`? Do I really have to add `or $var = '0'` to my `test` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is taken from [XPath test if node value is number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854345/xpath-test-if-is-number)
Test the value against [NaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256038.aspx):

```
<xsl:if test="string(number(myNode)) != 'NaN'">
    <!-- myNode is a number -->
</xsl:if>
```

This is a shorter version:

```
<xsl:if test="number(myNode) = myNode">
    <!-- myNode is a number -->
</xsl:if>
```

```
<xsl:if test="number(0)">
```

the expression number(0) is evaluated to the boolean false() -- because by definition

boolean(0) is false()

Answer (score 5):

**This is perfectly according to the [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-boolean)**:

By definition `boolean(0)` is `false()`

**You want**:

```
<xsl:if test="number($var) = number($var)">
  <node att="{number($var)}" />
</xsl:if>
```

**Explanation**:

```
number($x) = number($x)
```

is `true()` exactly when `$x` is castable to a number.

If `$x` isn't castable to a number, both sides of the above comaparison evaluate to `NaN`, and by definition `NaN` isn't equal to any value, including `NaN`.

**Note**:

In case you want to check if `$var` is *integer*, then use:

```
<xsl:if test="floor($var) = $var">
  <node att="{$var}" />
</xsl:if>
```

or, alternatively:

```
<xsl:if test="not(translate($var, '0123456789', ''))">
  <node att="{$var}" />
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2.0, try using expressions such as `$var castable as xs:integer` or `$var castable as xs:double`.