# Conditional variable select in XSLT

Tags: variables, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want a variable to have the value of an element if the value is numeric, but if it's not then I want the variable to have the value `0`.

In other words, is there a simple equivalent of the following in XSLT?

```
var foobar = is_numeric(element value) ? element value : 0
```

Or how would you write this?

```
<xsl:variable name="foobar" select=" ? " />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In XPath 2.0 yes, you can use "`castable as`"

```
<xsl:variable name="foobar" as="xs:double"
   select="if (x castable as xs:double) then x else 0" />
```

Answer (score 17):

**XPath 1.0:**

```
<xsl:variable name="foobar">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number($value) = number($value)">
      <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Reference for this clever `number($value) = number($value)` numeric test:  [Dimitre Novatchev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3857478/290085) to ["Xpath test if is number" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854345/xpath-test-if-is-number).

Comment: Is there any reason why this approach may fail if your variable is returning a *node set*? I ask because if I define the variable as one or the other it works. But the moment I introduce the `xsl:choose` logic it don't work right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76941354/3016153

Answer (score 6):

You could use:

```
<xsl:variable name="x" 
              select="(ELEMENT[. castable as xs:double], 0)[1]"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="x" 
              select="sum(ELEMENT[. castable as xs:double])"/>
```

Comment: What does `(x, y)` do, in your first example?

Comment: @Svish, `(x, y)` forms a sequence of `x` and `y` but as `ELEMENT[. castable as xs:double]` yields the empty sequence if the content of `ELEMENT` is not a double the value is either a sequence of `(ELEMENT, 0)` or simply the sequence `(0)`. And the predicate `[1]` then selects `ELEMENT` or `0`.

Comment: @Svish so in particular if there is more than one `ELEMENT` child in the current context then my approach will always return `0` (because a sequence of more than one item is not `castable as xs:double`), whereas Michael's approach will return the first `ELEMENT` child which can be cast to `xs:double` (in the `(x, y)[1]` case) or the sum of all such `ELEMENT`s (in the `sum()` case), or `0` if none of them are appropriately castable.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanations. I'm going for @IanRoberts since that expresses most clearly what I actually want. Seems less hackish, hehe.