# Sum only numeric columns with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, sum

I have some XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<root>
    <line>
        <ResourceName>Ren</ResourceName>
        <Amount>20</Amount>
        <OtherAmount>5</OtherAmount>
        <SomeText>Nopls</SomeText>
    </line>
    <line>
        <ResourceName>Stimpy</ResourceName>
        <Amount>30</Amount>
        <OtherAmount>10</OtherAmount>
        <SomeText>Do_not_sum</SomeText>
    </line>
</root>
```

but importantly the number of 'columns' below line node could more or less and any name (dynamic varying).

I want to generate a HTML table with the node names as a header and a total for any numeric columns in the footer.

So far I have an XSLT as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="root">
<html>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="line[1]" mode="thead"/>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="line" />
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>Totals:</td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:variable name="amount1Lines" select="line/Amount"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($amount1Lines), '0.00')" />
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="line" mode="thead">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="thead"/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="thead">
    <th>
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
    </th>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="line">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="line/*">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but obviously the footer section is hardcoded for each column.

Can anyone determine some xsl that will sum *only* numeric columns and leave other columns blank in the footer. ie. In the example it would sum 'Amount' and 'OtherAmount' but not resourcename or sometext columns.

Comment: do you want to sum ALL numeric nodes? e.g., from the above sample code, you would expect a value of 65?

Comment: No. I want a table where each column (eg. Amount) has a sum in the footer. So Amount has 50 in the footer and OtherAmount has 15 in the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By repeating the same pattern you have for `thead` for `tfoot`, and then using [this trick from Dimitre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3857478/314291) for determining whether a sample column is numeric, you can total the columns as follows:

```
<tfoot><tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="line[1]/*" mode="tfoot"/>
</tr></tfoot>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="tfoot">
    <td>
        <xsl:variable name="columnName" select="local-name()"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="number(//line[1]/*[local-name()=$columnName]) = 
                      number(//line[1]/*[local-name()=$columnName])" >
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(//line/*[local-name() = $columnName])" />
        </xsl:if>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

**Edit** The existing line `<tr>` template will do fine for the footer as well (Thanks @anon editor).

**Re: 2 Tables**

Given the `xml`:

```
<xml>
    <root>
        <line>...</line>
        ...
    </root>
    <root>
        ..
```

You can change the summation to restrict to just the current `root` data by walking up the `ancestor` axis to find lines for just 'this' root:

```
<xsl:if test="number(ancestor::root/line[1]/*[local-name()=$nodeName]) 
              = number(ancestor::root/line[1]/*[local-name()=$nodeName])" >
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(ancestor::root/line/*[local-name() = $nodeName])" />
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: IT WORKS. You roxxor.

Comment: If I have another block with "<root2>" how can I avoid picking up lines from the other block and still have a generic template for the footer sum? ie. Only total children of "root" for root lines, and children of "root2" for root2 lines?

Comment: Updated - although you might have quicker response if you ask a new question next time :-)