# use xpath function ends-with() to find digit

Tags: xml, xpath

I would like to loop and find elements starting with a string and ends with a digit but I'm not sure how to do it with `ends-with()`

I have this code here

```
*[starts-with(name(), 'cup') and ends-with(name(), '_number')]
```

**ps: not sure what version of xpath the application is using**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XPath 2.0

This is straight-forward in XPath 2.0, where this expression,

```
//*[matches(name(), '^cup.*\d$')]
```

will select all elements whose name starts with `cup` and ends with a digit, as requested.

### XPath 1.0

Since XPath 1.0 lacks regex, `ends-with()`, and functions to test if a string is a numbers, your request gets to be more complicated with XPath 1.0.  Here's one possible working solution:

```
//*[starts-with(name(), 'cup') 
    and number(substring(name(),string-length(name()))) 
      = number(substring(name(),string-length(name())))]
```

Note that the second clause is [a clever way by Dimitre Novatchev to test 
 in XPath 1.0 whether a string is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3857478/290085).

Here's a shorter way to check for ending in a digit in XPath 1.0:

```
//*[starts-with(name(), 'cup') 
    and not(translate(substring(name(),string-length(name())), '0123456789', ''))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `ends-with` is not in Xpath 1.0 , you must be using atleast XPath 2.0 , then you can use [`matches()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) to match string with digit at end like:

`matches(name(), '.*\d+$')`

`then xpath will be :

`*[starts-with(name(), 'cup') and matches(name(), '.*\d+$')]` or just like as @kjhughes mentioned in his answer :

`*[matches(name(), '^cup.*\d+$')]`