# XPath for numeric latitude and longitude values in R?

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I have an XML file with measurements. I would like to select only those `measurementSiteName`'s that have a latitude and longitude using R.

With this code chunk I can select the name of a site with a specific latitude:

```
doc <- xml2::read_xml('test.xml')
query <- ".//measurementSiteName/values/value[../../../measurementSiteLocation/locationForDisplay/latitude/text() = '52.23634']"
xml2::xml_text(xml2::xml_find_all(doc, query))
```

However, there are site names without a latitude or longitude. I don't know how to do this.
The latitude and longitude nodes may be missing or empty.

Can somebody please help me out? Please find attached `text.xml`

```
<measurements>
  <measurement>
    <measurementSiteName>
      <values>
          <value>abc</value>
      </values>
    </measurementSiteName>
    <measurementSiteLocation>
      <locationForDisplay>
        <latitude>52.23634</latitude>
        <longitude>4.503404</longitude>
      </locationForDisplay>
    </measurementSiteLocation>
  </measurement>
  <measurement>
    <measurementSiteName>
      <values>
          <value>def</value>
      </values>
    </measurementSiteName>
    <measurementSiteLocation>
      <locationForDisplay>
        <latitude></latitude>
        <longitude></longitude>
      </locationForDisplay>
    </measurementSiteLocation>
  </measurement>
  <measurement>
    <measurementSiteName>
      <values>
          <value>ghi</value>
      </values>
    </measurementSiteName>
    <measurementSiteLocation>
      <locationForDisplay>
      </locationForDisplay>
    </measurementSiteLocation>
  </measurement>
</measurements>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//measurementSiteLocation
  [locationForDisplay[    number(latitude)  = number(latitude) 
                      and number(longitude) = number(longitude)]]
```

will select all `measurementSiteLocation` elements with a `locationForDisplay` child that has `latitude` and `longitude` children with numeric values.

**References:**

- Numeric predicate technique: See [Dimitre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3857478/290085) to [XPath test if node value is number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3854345/290085)